# Iphone Restkit RKObjectLoader error

Tags: iphone, three20, restkit

I have created an app, for Iphone, that uses Three20 and RestKit framework.

The app works almost perfectly, but there is a problem in the following situation:

I have a view that calls another using the method `TTOpenURL(@"tt://reports");`

In my loadView i have the method

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/checks" queryParams:params delegate:self];
```

I have those two methods for the returns:

```
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray*)objects 
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didFailWithError:(NSError*)error
```

Everything works correctly, the view shows the results and after i selected the back button everything keeps running correctly.
But if I open the screen and select the back button before finishing the loading, 
an error occurs in the class `RKObjectLoader` in the method `- (void) didFinishLoad (RKResponse *) response;`

most precisely in line

```
if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(request:didLoadResponse:)]) {
```

Does anyone know how can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Andre

Comment: Andre, please include as much information as possible to help you resolve this error. For example, you may include the traceback you're getting when error occurs.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add the following to your controller's (RKObjectLoaderDelegate's) dealloc method:

```
[[RKRequestQueue sharedQueue] cancelRequestsWithDelegate:self];
```